# How to check the current URL in qweb?

Tags: odoo, qweb

I would like to check current URL in qweb to change the text in a button.

I am working in an online store based in Odoo 11.0 community

```
<button t-if="current_URL ==/shop">Filters OFF</button>
<!--Since current_URL would be something like "/shop/category/laptops?filter=5-44" if there were any filters applied -->
<button t-else="">Filters ON</button>
```

I simply don't know if there is something like "current_url" or any other parameter/variable that qweb would understand and could fetch as a property of the current page or if I should try to do this all in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

```
<button t-if="request.httprequest.url == '/shop'">Filters OFF</button>
<!--Since current_URL would be something like "/shop/category/laptops?filter=5-44" if there were any filters applied -->
<button t-else="">Filters ON</button>
```

ref: https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseRequest.url it may be helpful to find other request property